# iOS - dismissing a facebook window do not fires dismissViewController completion block

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ipad, twitter

I have this code compiled and running for iOS 6.

```
SLComposeViewController *control = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:...];
[control setInitialText:...];
[control addURL:...];
[control setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // do something
    }];
}];
[self presentViewController:control animated:YES completion:nil];
```

if this is used as a Twitter control, it works fine, but if it is used as a Facebook control, the completion block of the dismissViewController is not called, ever!!! (the doSomething part never runs).

I thought this could have something to do with the controller being dismissed not on the main thread, so I have changed that to

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
             // do stuff... 
         }];
});
```

without success.

Is this an iOS 6 bug? how do I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.6 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do stuff
});
```

this is probably an iOS 6 bug related to the dismissViewController API.

EDIT: I have created a more powerful solution and **[posted here](https://github.com/lunarbase/SLComposeViewController-Extended/blob/master/README.md)**